# How can I remove extra error bars in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, errorbar

[image]

Does anyone know why suddenly my error bars are showing up in each column instead of their designated one? It was working before, but my x-axis was in the wrong order, showing "0" "16" "32" "8". I changed Well to be a factor with:

```
welldata$Well_f <- factor(welldata$Well, levels = c('0', '8', '16', '32'))
```

but once I did that it changed my error bars to go everywhere instead of only in their corresponding well. Can anyone help me fix this without reversing my facet_wrap order?

```
ggplot(welldata, aes(x = E2F4, y = Colonies, color = Clone, fill = E2F4)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(data = error_data, aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), width = 0.2, color 
    = "black") +
  labs(title = "HT29 Colony Survival",
      x = "Concentration of SN-38 (nM)",
      y = "Number of colonies") +
      scale_color_manual(values = c('11' = "darkturquoise", "7" = "darkturquoise", 
      "2" = "darkturquoise","Control"= "darkorchid")) +
   scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("-/- = E2F4 Knockout", "+/+ = E2F4 Wild Type")) +
   guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 3)), fill = 
   guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 2))) +
 facet_wrap(~Well_f, nrow = 1, strip.position = "bottom") +
   theme_minimal() +
   theme(strip.placement = "outside",
   panel.spacing = unit(0, "cm"),
   strip.text = element_text(size = 10, margin = margin(b = 15)),
   legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
   plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(b = 10)))
```

When I write "Well" in facet_wrap in goes back to the correct error bars but the ordering gets messed up again. Put it back as "Well_f" and the ordering works but all the extra error bars come back.

data:

```
structure(list(E2F4 = c("+/+", "+/+", "+/+", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", 
"-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "+/+", "+/+", "+/+", 
"+/+", "+/+", "+/+", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", 
"-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "+/+", "+/+", "+/+"), Colonies = c(1052, 
983, 1057, 497, 464, 437, 111, 81, 85, 40, 42, 43, 523, 523, 
636, 646, 730, 749, 58, 60, 53, 705, 746, 785, 54, 82, 80, 1618, 
1470, 1505), Clone = c("Control", "Control", "Control", "7", 
"7", "7", "11", "11", "11", "2", "2", "2", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "2", "2", "2", "7", 
"7", "7", "11", "11", "11", "Control", "Control", "Control"), 
Well = c("32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", 
"32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", 
"32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", 
"32", "32"), Hour = c(24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48), Well_f = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("0", 
"8", "16", "32"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -30L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

error data:

```
error_data <- data.frame(
E2F4 = c("-/-", "+/+", "-/-", "+/+", "-/-", "+/+", "-/-", "+/+"),
Colonies = c(2837.3333, 1911.33333, 137, 259.6667, 95.666, 
557.6667, 74.333, 757.3333),
Well = c("0", "0", "8", "8", "16", "16", "32", "32"),
Errors = c(334.02993877795, 103.568010, 158.745, 197.616630, 
93.0931, 133.82949, 66.515, 43.98106))

error_data <- error_data %>%
mutate(ymin = Colonies - Errors, ymax = Colonies + Errors)
```

Comment: The error data is missing.

Comment: Oh sorry just added!

Comment: I don't see any issues given the sample data you provided: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCXKH.png. (FYI, I also ran `error_data$Well_f <- factor(error_data$Well, levels = c('0', '8', '16', '32'))`, though I doubt it's contributing to this problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not directly asked, you may also want to see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76813306/draw-lines-between-facets-of-facet-grid/76870038#76870038). I think using facet_wrap is not the best option.

To solve your problem, I will add a line in your error data that matches the `facet_wrap` parameter you used for `welldata`.

```
error_data <- error_data %>%
  mutate(ymin = Colonies - Errors, ymax = Colonies + Errors) %>% 
  mutate(Well_f = factor(Well, levels = c('0', '8', '16', '32'))) ## added here
```